# How to retrieve lost itinerary confirmation from Cebu Pacific Air?

Tags: philippines

I have made a booking on Cebu Pacific at the BDO payment center, but I was not able to receive any confirmation on my email. Thus I could not view my itinerary receipt. I have tried many options so many times just to view my itinerary, but I failed and some of the response is I have a duplicate booking. So what should I do, because I have already paid the amount on my booking?

Answer (score 3):

You should go to the Cebu Pacific Air office in your city with your ID. Do not go to a travel agent (unless you bought your ticket from them) or bank. If you don't know where their office is, there is one in the airport if they fly there.

When you come to the office, you show them your ID and tell them the booking information you know (origin, departure, date), tell them you never received your booking and ask them to look it up for you.

Comment: If you can download your credit card statement showing the Cebu Pacific payment for your purchase. I'd print it out and take it along as well.